# User input never enters if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, input, integer

The point of the program is to have a user input an amount of integers endlessly (until they enter something other than an integer), and for each integer the user inputs, it should check if the integer is greater than or less than the value entered.

The problem: When the program runs, everything is fine until reaching

```
number = scanner.nextInt();
```

At this point, the user inputs their integer, but never makes it inside the following if statements. I would love a hint instead of an answer, but I'll take what I can get.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            System.out.println("Enter number: ");
            int number = 0;
            int minNumber = 0;
            int maxNumber = 0;
            boolean hasInt = scanner.hasNextInt();
            if (hasInt) {
                number = scanner.nextInt();
                if (maxNumber < number) {
                    maxNumber = number;
                }
                if (minNumber > number) {
                    minNumber = number;
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Your minimum number: " + number);
                System.out.println("Your maximum number: " + maxNumber);
                break;
            }
        } while (true);

        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you used a debugger to find out what is happening?

Comment: What leads you to think it's not getting to the `if` statements? What's happening instead? Try using a debugger or adding printouts to check your hypothesis.

Comment: I enter print statements throughout the code as "checkpoints" to see where it reaches, and as far as I can tell, that's where the problem starts.

Comment: It's not reaching the if statements, because if it did, the user input would update to the value entered I would think. It doesn't. It outputs the values intially declared.

Comment: What do the inputs look like?

Comment: Inputs that I have tested are 50, 25, 75, and then I enter a letter to break the program.

Comment: @Ben How do you enter the inputs into the console? Are they space separated, comma separated, newline separated? Are they even separated?

Comment: Inputs are entered one at a time, 50 <enter, 25 <enter>, 75 <enter>, a <enter> (intended break here)

Comment: @khelwood @tashkhisi @yusufX019 The OP is reading input correctly. They didn't make the common mistake of mixing `nextInt()` and `nextLine()`.

Comment: Initialize your variables outside the loop otherwise, they are initialized every time the loop runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's not reaching the if statements, because if it did, the user input would update to the value entered I would think. It doesn't. It outputs the values initially declared.

You're not getting the right output and you have a hypothesis that the cause is the code not entering the `if` statements. Following the scientific method, the next step is to test your hypothesis.

If you put printouts inside the `if` statements you'll see that they are indeed running. That's not it. The mistake must be elsewhere. You should collect more evidence and develop a new hypothesis.

**Hint:** Try printing out the values of your variables at the beginning **and** end of each iteration. I've marked the places below. Are they what you expect them to be? You're going to see an anomaly that should point you in the right direction.

```
do {
    System.out.println("Enter number: ");
    int number = 0;
    int minNumber = 0;
    int maxNumber = 0;

    // Print number, minNumber, and maxNumber.

    boolean hasInt = scanner.hasNextInt();
    if (hasInt) {
        number = scanner.nextInt();
        if (maxNumber < number) {
            maxNumber = number;
        }
        if (minNumber > number) {
            minNumber = number;
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Your minimum number: " + number);
        System.out.println("Your maximum number: " + maxNumber);
        break;
    }

    // Print number, minNumber, and maxNumber.
} while (true);
```

Comment: I wish I saw this first, thank you for the debugging tip. I had assumed the program never entered the if statements because the variables never updated. I should have debugged more thoroughly.

Comment: Or just use an actual debugger and go through the code step by step in 1 minute. No print statements, no headache, no time spending on writing a question on stackoverflow.

Comment: You're right Don, I wasn't aware of the debugger as a tool, just as a concept. I've been learning via Udemy, and the course I'm enrolled in hasn't mentioned it yet. I'll use it in the future. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Your `minNumber` and `maxNumber` declarations should be out side of the loop. Also, you need to initialize the values as below to get correct min and max comparison with the entered values only:

```
int minNumber = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int maxNumber = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
```

In print statement instead of `minNumber` you are printing `number`!

Comment: This is correct but I suggest letting the OP figure it out for themselves so they learn better.

Comment: My program is still buggy, but this got me on the right path, thank you!